# Parse RSS Feed With Unique Elements

Tags: php, parsing, rss, simplexml

I have used PHP with simplexml to parse RSS using standard elements before like `<title> <pubDate>` etc.  But how would I parse something custom to the feed like `<xCal:location>` or `<xCal:dtstart>` that uses an xCal data element?

Something like `$item->xCal:dtstart`  will error out.  How would I collect this data element?

A sample of a feed like this:  http://www.trumba.com/calendars/vd.rss?mixin=236393%2c236288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$feedUrl = 'http://www.trumba.com/calendars/vd.rss?mixin=236393%2c236288';
$rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);

$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

//print_r($ns);
$xCal = $xml->channel->children($ns['xCal']);
echo ($xCal->version)."<br />";

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
    //print_r($item);
    $itemxTrumba=$item->children($ns['x-trumba']);
    echo $itemxTrumba->masterid."<br />";
}
//print_r($xCal);
```

Comment: Assuming you are using PHP 5.2 or higher (why wouldn't you be? `;)`), you don't need to mess around with the array of namespaces, just pass `true` as the second parameter to `->children` and use the prefix directly (e.g. `$item->children('x-trumba', true)->masterid`).

Answer (score 0):

The "something custom" is an XML namespace. Search for existing answers regarding SimpleXML and namespaces.

Basically, what you need is the `->children()` method: `$item->children('xCal', true)->dtStart`